# On using recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion

While implementing a lexical analyzer in C, I found myself writing a recursive code:

```
// Return a List of Tokens
List Lexer_run(const char* input) {
    if(input[0] == '\0') {
        return new_List();
    } else {
        // ... Find Token and possibly advance in input for a few characters
        return List_add(Lexer_run(nextInput), newToken);
    }
```

Consider another example in an implementation of linked list

```
List_length(List* this) {
    if(!this) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + List_length(this->next);
    }
}
```

I am wondering if I can always use such recursive code in C or if I should avoid it unless the case
really requires recursion (for example recursive descent parser or a tree structure)

**What I think so far**

Advantages of recursion:

- readable and elegant

Drawbacks:

- will rapidly cause a stack overflow (in my computer it's around 1'000'000 calls)
- can be inefficient comparing to an iterative version

Solutions:

- use tail-call optimization and let the compiler transform my recursion into loops but I find tail-call code to be less readable.
- Increase stack size for my program

**Note**

My question is not specifically about my examples but rather a general question if one should use
recursion in C.

Comment: To answer to the only question in this post is: No, avoid it unless it brings something *significant* besides fewer keystrokes.

Comment: "I am wondering if I can always use such recursive code in C" - you can always use recursion, since C permits any function to call itself (even `main()`). You are also encouraged to write recursive code if it's more readable than its iterative counterpart. Yes, recursion can be slower. Yes, it can cause stack overflow. And that doesn't always matter -- don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: @WhozCraig I beg to differ. It's not about "fewer keystrokes". Recursion can be significantly easier to understand (and if I'm not inside a tight loop computing billions of floating-point numbers per second, I don't really care about the "efficiency" I lost with recursion if the code is more readable and easier to grasp.)

Comment: Nothing dictates that a recursive function must use recursion to all tasks -- a function parsing e.g. xml data or even a recursive descent parser can and should use both iterative and recursive control mechanisms where appropriate.

Comment: @H2CO3 Would you still use tail recursion or normal one ?

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not against recursion and I wouldn't go as far as "don't use it".  But if there is a real threat of getting SO it's not about pre-mature optimization anymore. It is about ensuring the solution works for the specified possible input. You cannot wave it off so easily. I also think that "(really) more readable code" falls into *significant*. On a side note I encountered not-so-few algorithms where the recursive version was actually harder to grasp.

Comment: Significantly fewer keystrokes means often significantly smaller code footprint too; the benefits are both material (=$$$) and mental. Compacting an algorithm to fewer but more powerful concepts cleans the mind of the programmer from unessential (=trash), which means productivity (=profit).

Comment: I would even call the 2nd code, a great example where recursive algorithm is harder to grasp. What's the purpose of using recursion for such implicitly iterative task as moving to next element until there exists one. Besides making up an example. I will hardly believe anyone that it's easier to understand than even a one-liner `for` loop for the same task.

Comment: @luk32 Sure. And I wouldn't use recursion for it either. I was only trying to point out that "recursion is slow and you should avoid it" is an overstatement.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sry I was late in responding to your comment; The "understandable" property you cite is among the *significant* things I mentioned, but for me the bottom line is the single responsibility principle: Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*. The OP's linked-list-length recursion algorithm is a *classic* example of where *not* to use recursion. An iterative solution is not only safer and faster, its even easier to understand, and thus recursion brings *nothing* to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule, you want to use recursion for tasks that are inherently recursive, such as walking recursive data structures, serializing structures defined recursively, or producing recursive structures from "flat" input (e.g. parsing a language). You do not want to apply recursion for tasks that can be expressed in terms of iteration, such as walking linear data structures.

Recursion is a powerful mechanism, but using it in place of iteration is like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer <sup>*</sup>. Memory efficiency and a possibility of stack overflow are both very important considerations, but they are secondary to understandability of your code. Even if you eliminate the negative consequences of applying recursion where an iteration is sufficient by letting the compiler optimize tail call for you, readers of your program would be scratching their heads trying to understand first what you did, and then why you did it.

When you apply recursion to a recursive task (trees, recursive descent parsers, divide and conquer algorithms that process the entire input, searches with backtracking) your code becomes more readable, because it matches the task at hand. On the other hand, when you apply recursion to an inherently non-recursive task, your code becomes harder to read.

<sup>*</sup> This metaphor on recursion vs. iteration is borrowed from an introductory chapters of one of Dijkstra's books.

Answer (score 2):

Tail call optimization is frankly not to be trusted. There's too many gotchas which can scare the optimizer away from applying it in apparently innocuous cases. Be glad that it's there, but don't rely on it.

Because of this (and because of the fixed stack size), you generally want to avoid recursion unless you actually need its implicit stack structure [you don't, for your `List_length`]. Even then, be aware of the potential for stack overflows.

The primary benefit of writing recursive functions is readability. That makes them "first draft" material for algorithms like recursive descent which have a naturally recursive structure. Then rewrite them as iterative (with a stack as necessary) if/when you run into trouble.

A side benefit of doing things that way: you can keep the recursive version around as a reference implementation, and unit test them to ensure they are equivalent.

Comment: +1 for the idea of leaving it around as a reference for testing. I think it's not as obvious as it should be.